# Print horizontal histogram for letters in file. How to scale it? Java

Tags: java, file, histogram

I would like to count the occurences of letters in a text file and draw a horizontal histogram. However, the longest bar should have the length of `50` stars. It's not a problem, when I have, the number less than `50`, but how to scale it so I have everything on a histogram?

I came up with this formula: `50 - 50 * histogram[i] / maxnum` where `50` is the maximum length of the bar, `histogram[i]` is the number of occurences of the `i-th` letter in an alphabet and `maxnum` is the number representing the number of occurences of the  most common letter in my file.

```
int[] histogram = new int[26];     
String alphabeth = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Here's how I build the histogram:

```
while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null){
     for (int i =0;i< line.length();i++){
          int index = alphabeth.indexOf(line.charAt(i));
          if (index != -1)
            histogram[index]++;  
     }
}
```

I look for the `maxval`:

```
int maxnum = histogram[0];
        for (int p=1; p<histogram.length;p++){
            if (maxnum < histogram[p]){
                maxnum = histogram[p];
            }
        }
```

And that's how I draw it:

```
for (int i=0; i<alphabeth.length(); i++){
            System.out.print(alphabeth.charAt(i) + " ");
            int count = histogram[i];
                for (int k=0; k<50-50*histogram[i]/maxval; k++){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
        }
```

Is it right?

Comment: could you use a histogram based on the percent of each letter in the file? then you wouldn't have to worry about the max 50 number of stars? Perhaps take each percent and divide by 2 so you only print 50 stars when that character is 100% of the file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an sense in the 50-50. Can't you just remove the first 50?

Is histogram[i] or maxval of type float or double? This would be needed for the division to not return an integer value.

Btw: You should really used brackets in your formula. And it might be a good idea to calculate the number of stars to print seperately and store it in a separate variable and not calculating it within the header of the for loop.

Comment: In `histogram[i]` I have an integer - the number representing the number of occurences of the `i-th` letter in alphabet. `maxval` is as well an integer. I edited the question and provided some details.

Comment: Then you should make one of the variables to a float for example.
Just check out the following code to understand what is going on:
    `System.out.println(5 / 2);` // two integers => result is of type integer
    `System.out.println(5.0f / 2);` // float and integer => result is of type float

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your 50 logic is that it skews the look of the data when a char does occur 50 times and all others don't. If you use a percent, your data will make sense in the histogram no matter the number of occurrences of one character. Below is some code I used to create a basic histogram that outputs the number of stars based on the percentage

```
     HashMap<Integer, Integer> alphabet = new HashMap<>();
     double totalChars = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
         Random ran = new Random();
         int x = ran.nextInt(500) + 1; //create some random amount of char occurrences
         alphabet.put(i, x);
         totalChars += alphabet.get(i); //get the total char count
     }

     System.out.println("Total Chars: " + totalChars);
     for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
     {
         System.out.print(i + " [" + ((double)alphabet.get(i))/totalChars * 100 + "%]: ");
         for(int j = 0; j < ((double)alphabet.get(i))/totalChars * 100; j++)
         {
             System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }
```

Every run of the program it generates random occurrences so you can see how the historgram behaves and looks based on percents.

Output:

```
Total Chars: 6898.0
0 [6.494636126413453%]: *******
1 [2.7544215714699916%]: ***
2 [3.0878515511742535%]: ****
3 [3.1603363293708324%]: ****
4 [4.914467961728037%]: *****
5 [1.7396346767178894%]: **
6 [0.8408234270803132%]: *
7 [4.450565381269933%]: *****
8 [3.102348506813569%]: ****
9 [1.0872716729486807%]: **
10 [6.668599594085242%]: *******
11 [7.060017396346767%]: ********
12 [3.0878515511742535%]: ****
13 [5.131922296317773%]: ******
14 [1.348216874456364%]: **
15 [5.131922296317773%]: ******
16 [2.638445926355465%]: ***
17 [1.290229051899101%]: **
18 [3.4067845752391994%]: ****
19 [1.6526529428819947%]: **
20 [7.089011307625398%]: ********
21 [6.364163525659612%]: *******
22 [5.682806610611771%]: ******
23 [5.769788344447666%]: ******
24 [5.030443606842563%]: ******
25 [1.0147868947521022%]: **
```